# How can i share a gif file through intents from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-storage

i am displaying a gif file in imageView from firebase.
and now i want to share it through intents when user clicks share button.
but i am not able to do it.
i am using this code but when user clicks the app is getting closed.

```
 public void sharegif(){
        String baseDir = MainActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir() + "/gm_gif_1.gif";
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        File file = new File(baseDir);
        try {
            byte[] readData = new byte[1024 * 500];
            InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(getResources()
                    .getIdentifier("gm_gif_1.gif", null, null));

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int i = fis.read(readData);

            while (i != -1) {
                fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                i = fis.read(readData);
            }

            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
        }

        baseDir = file.getPath();

        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider", new File(baseDir));
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
        shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
    }
```

Comment: If your app crashes you did not catch an exception that was thrown. Find out please and tell us. Look in the Logcat.

Comment: `catch (IOException io) {
        }` Better: `catch (IOException io) { io.printStacTrace(); Toast(..inform user..); return;
        }`

Comment: You should add a flag for grant read permission.